# Script Change on Keydown Working Locally, but not on Server

Tags: javascript, arrays, keycode

When tested locally the example below works perfectly. It cycles through different jsmovermaps on mouse press, but when I test this on the server it doesn't update the jsmovermap relevant to cursor press. I have uploaded the maps correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ireland Map</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.qtip.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="map" id="map">
    </div>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    <script src="jsmovermap1.js" id="s1"></script>
<script>
x=1;
//alert(x);
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 38) {
        //alert('The "UP" key is being held down...?');
        x=x+1;
        //alert(x); 
        //script.src = "jsmovermap"+(x)+".js";

        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "jsmovermap"+(x)+".js";;
        s.innerHTML = null;
        s.id = "map";
        document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("map").appendChild(s);
        //alert(s.src);

    }
    if (evt.keyCode === 40) {
        //alert('The "DOWN" key is being held down...?');
        x=x-1;
        if(x<1){
            x=1}

        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "jsmovermap"+(x)+".js";;
        s.innerHTML = null;
        s.id = "map";
        document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("map").appendChild(s);      
        //alert(x);
    }

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE!

This is what the console is spitting out after a number of cursor presses.

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://jeremiahambrose.com/maptest/Test/jsmovermap23.js".

Comment: if it is working on localhost but not working on server, it is _mostly_ becuase you have uploaded your js files in wrong place and html can't find them. Moreover, [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) is awesome

Comment: @Barmar I have created a specific folder and checked this multiple times. There is no clear reason why it is not calling them. I have added what the console is throwing up after a number of cursor presses.

Comment: delete your duplicate jsmovermaps, and upload your original jsmovermap1.js, after that do a cache-clean refresh using ctrl+f5. it is indeed cannot find your script file.

Comment: I have just tried this, still having the same problem. On cursor up it is reloading jsmovermap1, while locally it changes to jsmovermap2. The alert on my browser is giving me http://jeremiahambrose.com/maptest/Test/jsmovermap2.js, which indicates that the script is being created.

Comment: actually it is working with me. on http://jeremiahambrose.com/maptest/Test/jsmover.html when i press key up, different alerts are coming such as jsmovermap2,3,4,5..

Comment: @owlwink Why did you address that comment to me? I didn't write anything for you to respond to.

Comment: The error you're getting is due to a problem with the webserver configuration. It's not mapping the file extension `.js` to MIME type `application/javascript`.